# Problems after Installing iperf 3.7.0

Tags: linux, iperf, iperf3

I was just installed the latest version of iperf3 in Ubuntu 18.4. First I cloned the files from iperf's GitHub repository and proceeded wit the installation process:

- ./configure
- make
- make install

I ran make check and all tests passed.

But when I invoke iperf3 I get the following message:

```
$ iperf3
iperf3: error while loading shared libraries: libiperf.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

iperf3 is installed but somehow if failing to run

```
~$ whereis iperf3
iperf3: /usr/local/bin/iperf3
```

Are some libraries missing?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming help with your own code. You might try asking on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Comment: The executable `iperf3` is hard coded to use `../../usr/lib/libiperf.so.0`. ... Two configure examples that will work : `./configure --prefix=/home/[name]/tmp/iperf/usr` ... and `./configure --prefix=/usr`